# How to call function from opnet

Tags: matlab, opnet

The problem is the integration of matlab and opnet 
If I have a function in matlab z=f(x,y)
How can I call it from the process model of a node in opnet?

Comment: network simulator @m02ph3u5

Comment: What languages does `opnet` support? You can basically call `MATLAB` functions from any major programming language, but I am unable to find any documentation for `opnet`

Comment: it is a network simulator supports C languages @Daniel

Comment: Then it's just the question how to call matlab from c.